# Generated values aren't updated in Global Properties (soapUI)

Tags: properties, soapui

- When I run *test cases individually*, values are updated in *Global Properties*.
- When I run *test suite* which contains 2 test cases by using test runner, at the time values aren't updated in *Global Properties*.

I am still able to see the old values which were generated when I ran the individual test cases.

Comment: It is noticed from the tests that the `global property values` are being changed during test execution and it is just  that changed value is not visible after the execution is complete. If you want, you may add assertions and see.

Comment: Oh well, looks like it's not possible with global properties. Test case properties do work though (in Soapui 5.x at least, haven't tried 4.x).